# MySQL Error 1157 while updating, however i'm using the primary key in the where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a 1157 error

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.
>     To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

when I try to execute this statement

```
UPDATE ip 
SET 
    ip_countryCode = 'GB',
    ip_countryName = 'United Kingdom',
    ip_city = 'London' 

WHERE BINARY ip_ip >= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.0') AND 
      BINARY ip_ip <= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.255');
```

This is the create table of the `ip` table

```
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
  `ip_ip` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `ip_last_request_time` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_city` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `ip_countryCode` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `ip_countryName` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
/*
more 23 columns have been omitted for readability
*/
  PRIMARY KEY (`ip_ip`),
  KEY `countryCode_index` (`ip_countryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What am I doing wrong here ? why I'm getting this error however the *Primary* key is used in the where clause ?

Comment: Just a guess - maybe the `BINARY` keyword is considered a function so the WHERE clause is not using the primary key directly but instead a set of values derived from the primary key.

Comment: @schtever hmmm, thank you , that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to just use the key column, you have to use it in a way that allows the index to be used to find the rows. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates):

> It is possible for UPDATE and DELETE statements to produce an error in safe-updates mode even with a key specified in the WHERE clause, if the optimizer decides not to use the index on the key column.

Since you're testing the value of `BINARY ip_ip` rather than just `ip_ip` itself, it can't use the index, so you get the error.

Can you use a function to convert the result of `INET6_ATON()` to `varbinary`, instead of using the `BINARY` operator on the column? Then it should be able to use the index and you won't get an error.

```
UPDATE ip 
SET 
    ip_countryCode = 'GB',
    ip_countryName = 'United Kingdom',
    ip_city = 'London' 

WHERE ip_ip BETWEEN CAST(INET6_ATON('2.57.77.0') AS BINARY(16)) AND 
                    CAST(INET6_ATON('2.57.77.255') AS BINARY(16);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` before the update query. Be careful when using this as it can do unintended data modification.

Or you can try to include the column `ip_countryCode` in your where clause.

```
UPDATE ip 
SET 
    ip_countryCode = 'GB',
    ip_countryName = 'United Kingdom',
    ip_city = 'London' 

WHERE BINARY ip_ip >= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.0') AND 
      BINARY ip_ip <= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.255') AND ip_countryCode <> 'GB';
```

OR you can remove the BINARY function

```
WHERE ip_ip >= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.0') AND 
      ip_ip <= INET6_ATON('2.57.77.255');
```

Comment: thank you, but I wish I could know the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Safe update mode is enabled by default. This prevents overwriting large amounts of data accidentally. 

Using `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` means you know what you are doing, that is updating all the specified range of IP addresses.

Comment: I mean "why this error is triggered in spite of I'm using the primary key in the where clause" ?

Comment: It is because of the BINARY function. If you remove the BINARY function, then it should work fine without `AND ip_countryCode <> 'GB';`